# NoMethodError: private method `existence_check' called for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a very strange problem.

**Scenario**: I'm working on a collection of photo in Rails with MongoDB (mongoid gem), where each photo belongs to an album. Some mongo fields are provided by concerns and models are correctly namespaced. 
So,

Concerns: `MediaConcerns::Base`

```
module MediaConcerns
  module Base
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      field :photo_description, type: String
    end
  end
end
```

Concerns: `MediaCollectionConcerns::Base`

```
module MediaCollectionConcerns
  module Base
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      field :album_title, type: String
      field :album_description, type: String
    end
  end
end
```

And `MediaType::Photo` is:

```
module MediaType
  class Photo
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps::Short
    include MediaConcerns::Base

    embedded_in :photo_album, class_name: 'MediaCollection::PhotoAlbum'    
  end
end
```

While `MediaCollection::PhotoAlbum` is:

```
module MediaCollection
  class PhotoAlbum
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps::Short
    include MediaCollectionConcerns::Base

    embeds_many :photos, class_name: 'MediaType::Photo'
  end
end
```

With concerns or not, the problem persist, and is related to the `embedded_in` and `embeds_many`.

By Rails console, when I try `MediaCollection::PhotoAlbum.new` it gives:

```
NoMethodError: private method `existence_check' called for MediaCollection::PhotoAlbum:Class
from /home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.0/lib/mongoid/relations/macros.rb:355:in `relate'
from /home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.0/lib/mongoid/relations/macros.rb:85:in `embeds_many'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_collection/photo_album.rb:10:in `<class:PhotoAlbum>'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_collection/photo_album.rb:2:in `<module:MediaCollection>'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_collection/photo_album.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

And the same for `MediaType::Photo.new`:

```
NoMethodError: private method `existence_check' called for MediaType::Photo:Class
from /home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.0/lib/mongoid/relations/macros.rb:355:in `relate'
from /home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.0/lib/mongoid/relations/macros.rb:56:in `embedded_in'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_type/photo.rb:15:in `<class:Photo>'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_type/photo.rb:2:in `<module:MediaType>'
from /home/marco/workspace/backend/app/models/media_type/photo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

What's the problem? If I remove (for debug only) the relationships `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`, the problem is solved, but i need to embed those documents!

Maybe Rails can't find the `:photos`, but I've specified `class_name: 'MediaType::Photo'` as mongoid documentation suggests, and the same is specified for `'MediaCollection::PhotoAlbum'`

I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason but not the solution, is a bug on the gem.

Read here: [github issue](https://github.com/sportngin/active_mongoid/issues/39)

Comment: What's the solution to this?